# How check if ACF custom field exist before insert or create CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, acfpro, wp-api

I need to validate if a custom field called family_id exists. If this family_id exists or is already created I need to send a message that it is duplicated and that a new one should be assigned.

NOTE: That id is not the one that wordpress assigns automatically is a custom field of ACF.

This is the custom field image

[custom field family_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyV1I.png)

And this is the code I have:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
            /*INSERT SINGLE family*/
        register_rest_route( 'api/v2','insert_family', [
            'methods' => 'POST',
            'callback' => 'insert_family'
        ] );
} );

function insert_family( $data ){

        $parameters = $data->get_params();

        $family = array(
            'post_title' => sanitize_text_field( $parameters['post_title'] ),       
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'family',
            'meta_input' => array(
                'featured_family' => sanitize_text_field( $parameters['featured_family'] ),
                'family_id' => sanitize_text_field( $parameters['family_id'] ),
            )
        );

        $family_id_created = wp_insert_post( $family );

        if ( is_wp_error( $family_id_id_created ) ) {       
            wp_die( $family_id_created->get_error_message() );
        } else {        
            return "The family was successfully";
        }
}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Are you pushing this from another site using the wp-json api, or are you saving this from the wp-admin?

Comment: I don't think ACF comes with a method to find a field value across _all_ post IDs. You could either get all your existing posts, loop over them, and call `get_field` for each one of them. Or use `get_posts` with a meta value query (ACF does store its data into the WP metadata tables), and see if that gets you any post back. Or make a native database query on the metadata table directly. (The latter would probably require some additional JOINing, if you wanted to take posts states like "in trash" into account as well at this point.)

Comment: Hi @HowardE I am inserting the data using postman but the idea is to insert it from another site using this endpoint.